# IntelliJ IDEA 13 JavaFX Artifact Versioning

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I'm switching from NetBeans to IntelliJ IDEA 13.0.2 for an existing JavaFX project and I've had very little trouble setting everything up, but I am missing one setting.  I'm using the artifact from IntelliJ to build MSI and EXE installers.  This works fine, but it always shows version 1.0 when I use the installer as well as in the name of the MSI and EXE files.  How do I change this to the correct version number?